# Как узнать число отправленных сообщений от конкретного пользователя с помощью Aiogram или pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, pyrogram

Есть такое дело: надо с помощью бота узнать сколько сообщений отправио определенный пользователь в телеграмме, как можно это сделать (Aiogram или pyrogram не имеет значения, оба варианта подойдут)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты имеешь ли ты ввиду подсчет ВСЕХ сообщений пользователя, то это невозможно. Если ты хочешь подсчитать сообщения в группе с ботом, или у него в лс - я бы на твоем месте создал что-то на подобии базы данных с помощью json и подсчитывал через:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda call: True)  # Контроль Сообщений
def take_message(message):
    pass
```

И вместо pass нужно добавлять единицу в бд по ID отправившего через `message.from_user.id`. Можно даже сортировать еще и по чатам через `message.chat.id`.

Comment: т.е. я так понял узнать сколько изначально в группе было сообщений нельзя?

Comment: думаю нет. Разве что как-то по всем сообщениям пробежаться, но вряд-ли так можно. Нужно изначально записывать в бд сообщения определенной группы. Если помог - поставь галочку у ответа))

Comment: спасибо, вы мне так или иначе помогли, поэтому галочку поставлю)